# Add new object to a nested array of objects based on name key of the array in react state

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, state, next.js13

I have an array in state which is below:

```
const [semiForm, setSemiForm] = useState([
    {
        name: '',
        image: '',
        exist: false,
        mId: null,
        mDetails: [
            {
                line_type: '',
                stock_type: '',
                gl_categories: '',
                planner_number: '',
                planner_name: '',
                buyer_number: '',
                buyer_name: '',
                serial_no: '',
                lot_process_type: '',
                master_planning_family: '',
                level_1_category: '',
                level_2_category: '',
                level_3_category: '',
                level_4_category: '',
                category_code: '',
                unit_of_measure: '',
                secondary_uom: '',
                purchasing_uom: '',
                shipping_uom: '',
                production_uom: '',
                component_uom: ''
            },
        ],
        prepared_by: '',
        recipe_no: '',
        approved_by: '',
        recipe_date: '',
        shelf_life: '',
        recipe_type: '',
        section: '',
        approval_date: '',
        ty_final_product: '',
        usable_trim: '',
        ty_aft_chill: '',
        wastage: '',
        pri_ingr: [
            {
                item_code: '',
                item_description: '',
                start_weight: '',
                left_weight: '',
                actual_qty: '',
                uom: '',
                yield: '',
                strg_container: '',
                cook_vessel: '',
                prepared_by: ''
            },
        ],
        steps: [
            {
                description: '',
                image: ''
            },
        ],
        eqp_used: [
            {
                name: ''
            },
        ],
    }
])
```

I want to add a new object to the "pri_ingr" array based on the "name" of the parent object.

I have tried with the below code where I am getting the "name" of the parent object, but even after setting the state it is not working.

```
const addPriIngr = (name) => {
    console.log(name)
    // return
    let newPriIngrObj = {
        item_code: '',
        item_description: '',
        start_weight: '',
        left_weight: '',
        actual_qty: '',
        uom: '',
        yield: '',
        strg_container: '',
        cook_vessel: '',
        prepared_by: ''
    }

    semiForm.map((item, index) => {
        console.log(item.name);
    if (item.name === name) {
        return { ...item, pri_ingr: [...item.pri_ingr, newPriIngrObj] }
    }
    return {
        ...item
    }
    })
}
```

Similarly I will use it of the other nested array of objects as well.

Please help sort this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping code looks fine. But, when calling `semiForm.map()`, you are not really changing anything. You have to consume the result of `semiForm.map()` in a useful way. Currently, you are only calling `.map()`, without doing anything with the result.

Instead of doing

```
semiForm.map((item, index) => {
    console.log(item.name);
    if (item.name === name) {
        return { ...item, pri_ingr: [...item.pri_ingr, newPriIngrObj] }
    }
    return {
        ...item
    }
});
```

You should do

```
let semiFormResult = semiForm.map((item, index) => {
    console.log(item.name);
    if (item.name === name) {
        return { ...item, pri_ingr: [...item.pri_ingr, newPriIngrObj] }
    }
    return {
        ...item
    }
});
setSemiForm(semiFormResult);
```

This way, you are telling React to use the result of the `.map()` call as the new state for `semiForm`.

I don't know what you mean by updating the state, but notice, that the state should be updated after calling `.map()` - not inside the function that is passed to `.map()`.

If this does not solve your problem, for example the data is not showing correctly, I believe the problem is not in your update to `semiForm`, but rather somewhere in your JSX binding. Maybe the bindings are not getting updated how you would expect them to?

Comment: Thanks it is now setting it properly.

Comment: Awesome! @H_alt Glad that I was able to help!